# Yii 1.1.15: unable to resolve request, but looks all fine

Tags: php, yii

Request:

```
/index.php?r=api/v1/searchCode
```

Check List

- I've a module called `ApiModule` in the file `ApiModule.php` in the directory  `protected/modules/api`
- I've `v1Controller.php` in the `api/controllers` dir.
- The `v1Controller.php` file contains `class V1Controller extends
  Controller`
- In the controller I've `public function actionSearchCode()`
- In `config/main.php` i've added `'api'` to enabled modules

What else ... ? Why I get 404 ?

```
Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "api/v1/searchCode
```

Note: All of my controllers extends 'Controller' and not 'CController'. It's not a typo

Comment: This is not correct (and nothing changes). All controllers must have full camel-case(NameOfController) but yii handle it as /nameOfController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a case of "case sensitivity". Try saving your controller as V1Controller.php instead of v1Controller.php and use r=api/v1/searchCode

Comment: Please, fix it your answer as is:file name MUST start with uppercase, so V1Controller.php, as you said, but it's not true, absolutely not true, that you must use /V1, it just works with /v1. If you fix the answer I'll choose as best answer, and thanks a lot

Comment: @realtebo I did not get your point. So what ultimately worked? You saved the file as V1Controller.php and called r=api/V1/searchCode? :)

Comment: Yes, It's also documented (I cannot search it now, but Yes, the first letter of the controller must be uppercase in file name and in class name, but must be (or could be) in lower case when used in url

Comment: @realtebo okay I am editing the answer for future ref. Thanks dude :)